Expansion of quantum eigenstate
I have a state given as,
$$|{\psi_{0k}}\rangle = \exp(-ik\cdot \hat{r}) |\psi_0\rangle$$
where $k = \frac{2\pi}{L} $ and $ |\psi_{0k}\rangle$ is the PBC ground eigenstate of Hamiltonian $$\hat{H_k}= \frac{1}{2m} \sum _{i=1}^N(p_i + \hbar k)^2 + \hat{v}.$$
Now using the identity, one can write,
$$\partial_k \text{ln} \langle\psi_0|\psi_{0k}\rangle = \frac{\langle\psi_0|\partial_k \psi_{0k}\rangle}{\langle\psi_0|\psi_{0k}\rangle}.$$
Now, there is a statement "$\langle\psi_0|\partial_k \psi_{0}\rangle$ is purely imaginary, then leading order expansion in $k $  gives,"
$$i\langle\psi_0|\partial_k \psi_{0}\rangle \cdot  k\approx -\text{Im ln}\langle\psi_0|\psi_{0k}\rangle $$
Which eventually relates to Polarization (defined dipolemoment per unit volume) in extended system under PBC.
I tried it by expanding the $\langle\psi_0|\partial_k \psi_{0k}\rangle$ and could not really arrive at the final result.
I am not able to get, How the expansion leads to the final result written in last equation. Any help would be much appreciated!

You might get answers here, but I think you're more likely to get an answer on https://physics.stackexchange.com/ .

It's plain elementary calculus.
Your malformed notation is execrable, and virtually incomprehensible, since k is a vector and should be denoted by $\vec k$, so that
$$|{\psi_{0k}}\rangle = \exp(-i\vec k\cdot \hat{r}) |\psi_0\rangle .$$
Consequently
$$\partial_{\vec k} \ln \langle\psi_0| \psi_{0k}\rangle = \frac{\langle\psi_0|\partial_{\vec k} |\psi_{0k}\rangle}{\langle\psi_0|\psi_{0k}\rangle}=\frac{\langle\psi_0| -i\hat r |\psi_{0k}\rangle}{\langle\psi_0|\psi_{0k}\rangle} .\tag{1}$$
The expansion of $\langle\psi_0| \psi_{0k}\rangle   $ in k around 0 is but
$$
\langle\psi_0|\psi_{0k}\rangle  = 1-i \langle\psi_0|\vec k \cdot \hat r  |\psi_{0k}\rangle +O(k^2). \tag{2}
$$
So
$$
\Im \ln \langle\psi_0|\psi_{0k}\rangle =\frac{1}{2i}(\ln \langle\psi_0|\psi_{0k}\rangle   -\ln \overline{\langle\psi_0|\psi_{0k}\rangle} )\\ =
\frac{1}{2i}\ln {\langle\psi_0|\psi_{0k}\rangle \over \overline {\langle\psi_0|\psi_{0k}\rangle } }=  -\langle\psi_0|\vec k \cdot \hat r  |\psi_{0k}\rangle  +O(k^2),\tag{3}
$$
recalling $\ln (1+x)= x +O(x^2)$.
Consequently, by the above (1),
$$i \vec k\cdot \partial_{\vec k}  \langle\psi_0| \psi_{0k}\rangle =  -\Im \ln \langle\psi_0|\psi_{0k}\rangle   +O(k^2),\tag{4}$$
as asserted.
